# Chrome stuck on print preview "loading preview" POS Printer

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing

i have Web Based POS System with thermal printer
the problem is everytime i print on chrome it always stuck on loading preview
i already tried the ff.

*Disable Print Preview
*--kiosk Mode(it prints but not all the lable, more on dots "." )

i use window.print() mode
it prints on firefox but not on chrome 
the problem on firefox is the barcode scanner there are some few digits missing
so i need to use chrome

I use win xp
is there anything to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the "few digits missing" isn't a css problem related to zoom/browser setting?

Chrome fails on many pages' printing but Firefox isn't always much better, you could look at removing certain elements when printing by setting display:none in a [print stylesheet](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/).